# How can I stretch and anchor a central view between a fixed-height header and footer, using Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I have a UIView that has 3 sub-views: a header, a center panel, and a footer. The header and footer are both fixed height, and I'm able to set their autosizing properties so that they behave like I want: the header stays anchored to the top and stretches to fit the screen (portrait or landscape), while the footer stays anchored to the bottom and also stretches with the screen.

The problem I'm having is with the center panel. I'm able to anchor it underneath the header, but I can't find any way of setting the autosizing properties for this center panel so that it stretches itself so that its bottom is just at the top of the footer. Everything I set seems to stretch it to the bottom of the main UIView (so it's stretched underneath the footer, which I don't want).

I can't do this in code (I think, unless there is a way) by overriding layoutSubviews, because I'm animating this outer view and I need the subviews to resize with the animation. Is there a way to do this in IB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### In code:

```
header.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
content.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
footer.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

### In Interface Builder:

Header:

[image]

Content:

[image]

Footer:

[image]

### Explanation:

The fixed margins (see annotated screenshot below) will keep the view's distance from the top and bottom of the super view's bounds constant. This is what you want since you have a fixed height header and footer.

This stuff is absolutely doable in code. There is nothing you can do in Interface Builder that you can't do in code as well.

[image]

Comment: Those IB settings are what I tried, but the center panel showed up with its bottom flush with the bottom of the superview, *underneath* the footer.

Comment: @MusiGenesis Make sure you've sized the view properly in interface builder then. I guarantee, 100%, that this solution is what you need. If the content is showing up underneath the footer then you need to double-check everything in IB because you went wrong somewhere.

Comment: I believe that I went wrong somewhere - that's why I asked the question.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - If you implemented `layoutSubviews` make sure you're calling the `super`'s implementation. Also, make sure you didn't set `AutoresizesSubviews` to `NO`. Barring those two things, make sure you properly setup the initial size in Interface Builder. Without seeing your project, or more information, there isn't much more I can say. You can easily verify the above technique with three images in a UIView and resize the UIView in interface builder.

Comment: I did a simple POC, and it does indeed work as you describe. Now I have to figure out what's wrong; it's part of a deep views-within-views structure, and I'm seeing that the center panel is stretched down to the bottom of the phone, not just to the bottom of its superview.

Comment: @MusiGenesis - Are you doing any custom view sizing? Sometimes I accidentally use `UIView`'s `frame` when I should be using `bounds` or vise-versa - that's something to look out for as well. But like I said - beyond the few ideas I've posted, I really have no way of helping without seeing the project or getting more info. I do think I answered the question though: "How can I stretch and anchor a central view between a fixed-height header and footer, using Interface Builder?"