# iPhone 5 specific screen size issues

Tags: ios6, iphone-5, xcode4.6

I'm working on app and need to support iPhone 5's 4 inch screen sizes. I initially designed the app and ran thru the XCode 4.6 simulator targeting iPhone 3.5 inch (retina and non retina displays) and switched to iPhone 5 from within the simulator. To my surprise, I was seeing a 1 inch space at the bottom of the screen beyond my several UIButtons. I have to scroll on the iPhone 5 simulator to view my UIButtons. What should I do here to support all screen sizes and make it look identical on all devices?. Also, my app only supports portrait mode for all devices (including all revisions of iPad) and I'm not using storyboards at all.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make the 3.5 inch screen and the 4 inch screen look identical because they are not. But you can make it look better on both. It's hard to tell what problem you're having without seeing the code. But I'll take my best guess to help you out.

If this view is part of a viewController that you've added as the rootViewController, then it should take care of expanding itself to fill the full screen, no matter what size the screen. However, if this is a subView within a viewController's view, then you should ensure that the view takes up the full screen. Often people hardcode the frame of the view to arbitrary numbers like so:

```
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)];
```

However, that is not portable between 3.5 and 4 inch screens. You want to do this:

```
[view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[view setFrame:self.view.window.bounds];  //sometimes i use this instead

//set autoresizing
view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

Apart from that, you can also use autoresizing to anchor components to the bottom of the screen, or to resize along with height of the screen.

See this post for how: [How can I stretch and anchor a central view between a fixed-height header and footer, using Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352511/how-can-i-stretch-and-anchor-a-central-view-between-a-fixed-height-header-and-fo)

Comment: I did this: checked autolayout option as my app will be supported from iOS 6 and beyond and everything looks great after that. One thing that I don't have an answer is when I use the iPhone 4 inch simulator to view the app, I'm seeing a scroll bar on the bottom and I have scroll little bit to the right to reveal a partially hidden button. Why is it so?. I have 4 UIButtons on the bottom and all are equally spaced and also centered.

Comment: possible issue: contentInset? if you set the contentInset left, it will force the inner views to move to the right a bit and force a scroll.

Comment: I'm not familiar with XCode 4.6. Can you tell me more about "contentInset" and how do I turn it off.

Comment: [scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

Comment: thank you. Do I have to add this line in viewDidLoad event for each of my .xib files (both for iPad and iPhone/iPod)?